# C# Generic wait method

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, timeout, predicate

I've got a variable being updated by another thread, and I want to check for different conditions on that variable at different times:

```
int x; //being modified by a thread


//some conditions I may want to check
x == 4

x < 0

x % 2 == 0
```

etc, just booleans.  I'd like to make a generic method into which I can pass a lambda function that returns a bool, and a timeout to wait for that condition to happen:

```
void WaitForEvent(lambda f, int timeOut)
{
    var t0 = DateTime.Now();
    while(true)
    {
        if(f)
            break;
        if((DateTime.Now() - t0).TotalSeconds > timeOut)
            throw new Exception("Timed out waiting for condition!");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

The method would be used like this:

```
WaitForEvent(()=> x > 5, 3);
```

Calling that would block until either x became greater than 5, or 3 seconds had elapsed, in which case an error would be thrown.  I know there has to be something built in to accommodate this, but what is it?

Comment: This post may be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703143/how-to-define-a-predicate-as-a-function-argument

Comment: Ah ok, I see.  And can I just do a Predicate<object> and pass in whatever I want?

Comment: Do you plan on polling the variable for changes? Or are you able to notify the waiting thread of variable changes?

Comment: I do plan on polling, because the conditions I need to check for are very specific and subject to change.